# Java method which check is it a number

Tags: java, numbers, int, double

I have wrote a method which takes a string and return true if its a valid single integer or floating number or false if its not.

My code:

```
public static boolean isDigit(String s)
    {
        boolean b;
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            b = true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            b = false;
        }

        try
        {
            Double.parseDouble(s);
            b = true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            b = false;
        }

        return b;
    }
```

I am sure there is a better way of writing it. Thank you

Comment: You want only single digits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: You can start by removing the first half of the method, since you don't do anything with the boolean value that it computes.

Comment: I would suggest to use a lib if you dont have to write yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java

Comment: If you're using Guava, `return Doubles.tryParse(s) != null;`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need check if it is `int`, since `int` number can also be parsed to `double`. It can be simplified to this:

```
public static boolean isDigit(String s)
{
    boolean b;

    try
    {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        b = true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        b = false;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Could be simplified further by dropping the `b` and `return`ing `true` and `false` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using Regular expression too.

```
 public static boolean isDigit(String s){
    String regex = "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    return b;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```
 return s.matches("[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
```

if "." is the separator for decimals

Comment: what about negative numbers/unary positive numbers?

Comment: answer edited, now works for negative numbers too, thanks @Reimeus

Answer (score 0):

The lightest solution is this one, also for code readability:

```
public boolean isDigit(String str) {
     try {
          Integer.parseInt(str)
          return true;
     } catch (NumberFormatException: e) { return false }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons StringUtils.isNumeric() to check if String is valid number

Examples:-

StringUtils.isNumeric("123") = true
StringUtils.isNumeric(null) = false StringUtils.isNumeric("") = false StringUtils.isNumeric(" ") = false